# as3 datagrid did not show arabic letters when running on mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, datagrid

I have created datagrid with filling static data in flash as3, the Arabic text in the datagrid does not accept new fonts, just the default font. 
When I export the file on "AIR on Android" and open it on my mobile, only English letters show up, but the Arabic letters are hidden.

Would you like to help me with this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you embedded  the  Arabic font you want to use? Most probably the default font on Android does not have Arabic symbols.

Comment: What is the default font in Android anyway?. **Arial Unicode** is the standard for covering all languages & symbols. You might have to leave datagrid alone and make your own table/grid & have the text via `textField` objects using embeded Arial Unicode font.

Comment: I have tried embedding fonts but no use, and what about table/grid? how can I create it, is there any code available?

Comment: Probably embedded fonts doesn't applied to DG correctly, first try it with a simple label. Also you can create your own item rendered for DG which give you more control over fonts.